# .Range and .InsertShift to copy a table on a new worksheet: overwriting data

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I have a basic question on `Sheet.Range` and `.Insert Shift:=xlDown`.
I would like to import on my worksheet a table of numbers which has just 2 columns.
Every time the macro reads 2 values (on the same row) in the original table, it should copy them in columns A and B in the worksheet and continue the process by writing another pair of numbers in the subsequent row.
If I write

`Sheet.Range("A1:B1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

 Sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "number 1 "

Sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "number 2"`

all I get in the end is the last pair of values from the original table.
In other words, the macro overwrites instead of moving down, row by row.
What should I amend? Thanks!
Avitus

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Can you please add more of your code? The above **should** work on its own.

Comment: Also be sure to reference the `insert` statement on a line of its own **without** any `with` statements. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=159723&p=583179#post583179

Comment: your code works for me. Just check **Sheet** is a valid sheet object. You need to add more code for us to trace out the issue.

Comment: On Sheet: I just used `Dim Sheet As Worksheet` followed by `Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`

Comment: Can you confirm you're seeing only the last result or all in reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code as posted apears to work, but puts the new data in in reverse order

Tested as

```
Sub demoAsIs()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To 4
        Sheet.Range("A1:B1").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "number " & 2 * i + 1
        Sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "number " & 2 * i + 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Sample data

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

To reverse the order, try this

```
Sub demo()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rNewData As Range
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set rNewData = Sheet.Range("A1:B1")
    For i = 0 To 4
        rNewData.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        ' rNewData now refers to the one row down from where it was
        rNewData.Cells(0, 1) = "number " & 2 * i + 1
        rNewData.Cells(0, 2) = "number " & 2 * i + 2
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

---

**Note on `xlDown` vs `xlShiftDown`**

Excel VBa provides many enumeration sets for parameters.  Each enumeration has an underlying numeric value. The  `Insert` method, `Shift` parameter uses the `XlInsertShiftDirection` Enumeration: `xlShiftDown`, `xlShiftToRight`.
`xlShiftDown` = -4121
Supplying an enumeration from another set that happens to have the same underlying numeric value (such as `xlDown`) will work, but is not strictly correct.

**Note on `Insert`**

The `Shift` parameter is optional.  If it is omitted, Excel decides which way to shift based on the shape of the range.

Comment: I can't believe you understood the question. This now makes sense if the result that the op sees is reversed and not simply the last record as the question suggests.

Comment: Thank you all for your support! Much appreciated. The reverse order issue was definitly present, but I considered it as a second order problem   :-).